# Is Javascript "eval" synchronous or asynchronous?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code:

```
eval(".....;a=5;b=10;");
eval("a+b");
```

If in case here the 1st eval runs for long time, will my next eval return an error mentioning as a and b are undefined, as the a and b values are initialised at the end of 1st eval. Will the eval method run synchronously or asynchronously

Comment: Totaly syncronous

Comment: eval is synchronous

Comment: [Obligatory warning about using eval](http://stackoverflow.com/q/86513/5743988)

Answer (score 2):

`eval` is synchronous.

Lets look at this example:

```js
console.log("before")
eval("console.log('eval')");
console.log("after");
```

You can see in that the print is in the order.

if it was asynchronous for example in this case:

```js
console.log("before");
setTimeout(()=>console.log("asynchronous"),0)
console.log("after")
```

The asynchronous run after.

Answer (score 2):

`eval` is synchronous in nature. But the evaluations/expressions inside the `eval` may have asynchronous code like `setTimeout` or `setInterval`.

For an instance.

**Method 1**: (synchronous example)

```js
eval('var a=5, b=10;');
eval('console.log(a+b)');
```

**Method 2**: (asynchronous example)

```js
eval('setInterval(function(){window["a"]=5, window["b"]=10;}, 1000)');
eval('console.log(typeof a)');
```

**Note**: Anyways, it's not recommended to use `eval` as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/86580/7055233