# One function gives different results in different consoles

Tags: javascript, function, variables, scope, console

I am new to JS, and currently study using Eloquent JS Book. In ch 10 there was a function below.
When i run it on localhost with live server, the output is 1 for both logs. However when using
the console given by the book or other sandbox js consoles I found online, the output is 2 and 1. If you know
why, please help

```js
const x = 1;
function evalAndReturnX(code) {
  eval(code);
  return x;
}

console.log(evalAndReturnX("var x = 2"));
// → 2
console.log(x);
// → 1
```

Comment: `eval` is definitely synchronous -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40968060/is-javascript-eval-synchronous-or-asynchronous. Which server are you running with locally?

Comment: In strict mode, `eval` will create a new scope for declarations.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between those environments would be [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode). Only in sloppy mode, `eval` is allowed to declare new variables in the function scope.

```js
"use strict"; /*
^^^^^^^^^^^^^ */
const x = 1;
function evalAndReturnX(code) {
  eval(code);
  return x;
}

console.log(evalAndReturnX("var x = 2")); // → 1, as it should be
console.log(x); // → 1
```

If you *want* to get `2` even in strict mode, I'd suggest you either do

```
var x;
eval("x = 2");
console.log(x);
```

or

```
console.log(eval("var x = 2" + "; x"))
```